# Please help me with this probability question

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, actuarial-science

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnhYg.png)
this is the problem. I already integrated the given integral for part (a) and I believe its finite for all values of p, but I'm confused about how I'd go about the expected value. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

$$E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x)dx$$

Comment: I know the formula, I’m just not sure how to apply it to the question. Do I need to go in and find every c value? I know the general formula.

Comment: @Lizzy Brodie If I understand the question correctly: $$E(X)=\int_{0}^{20}xc_{p}x^{-p}dx$$ $$=c_{p}\int_{0}^{20}x^{1-p}dx$$ and, because of your answer from part $a,$ I believe you can conclude that this is finite for all $p>0,$ as long as you show for $p=1$